# Method Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::failures does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I am trying to send an email in my laravel project but getting an error that `Method Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::failures does not exist.`. Here is the code below:

```
if (Mail::failures()){

            $res_data = [

                'msg' => __('Mail Send Failed'),

                'type' => 'danger'

            ];

        }

        return redirect()->back()->with($res_data);

    }
```

I don't know if the method is deprecated or what, but I tried everything

Comment: `failures()` is deprecated in laravel 9.11.0, Use `try catch` instead

Comment: It doesn't exist in 10